# Can I tell Windows 8.1 to always switch to a certain network, even if connected to another one already?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1, priority

At my grandma's place, I use a public network that's provided by the ISP of a neighbor to all the ISP customers. The network is public, but it requires a username and password to even connect to the network (you need to enter it while configuring your connection, not through a web portal). It's not that fast in Belgian terms (about 5-10 Mbps), but it's fast enough to be workable.

I am a customer of that ISP, and as such, I have that same network available at home. I also have a personal network that is A LOT faster, with speeds up to 185 Mbps. Obviously, I much rather have the 185 Mbps network than the 5 Mbps network.

I've noticed that, sometimes, when I come back from my grandma's place and had my laptop in sleep mode during transit, Windows still connects to the ISP network after leaving sleep mode, even though my personal network is set to a higher priority. I recently had this happen and didn't realize until I had troubles watching a stream on Twitch on high quality. I switched it over again and it was fixed, but I'd rather that the computer always prefers my personal network, even if I was previously connected to the ISP network.

Is it possible to tell Windows 8.1 to switch to higher priority networks if available, even if already connected to another network?

---

I switched to Windows 10, and I have the same issue still. `netsh wifi show properties` shows my personal network as highest priority, but it still autoconnects to the ISP network.

I'm handing out a 50 point bounty to whoever can give me an answer that works.

Comment: Can you not set your "better" network to be higher on the last of Windows preferred networks and then configure the network that's least preferred to have the option "connect to a more preferred network" set so that when your faster network is in range it'll connect to this even if already connected to the lesser preferred network?

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/view-preferred-wireless-networks to change priority. You'll need to edit the slower network properties by looking at its properties manually.

Comment: @BigChris My personal network is already configured at the highest priority. I don't know how to configure that option you mention because I'm using a Dutch W10 and I don't really recognize an option that's that. The closest I can find is "Search for other wireless networks while connecting (could also be connected) to this network", but I'm not sure if that's it. I'm fairly sure it was called differently during Windows 8.1 anyway.

Comment: See this page for the options I mean. It's right at the bottom: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27067/change-wireless-network-priority-to-make-windows-7-choose-the-right-network-first/ - although for Win7 the options are still the same for 10 I should think. You just need to get to the wireless network properties for the network you don't want to automatically be connected to if a better one is available

Comment: @BigChris Nope, Microsoft reworked that functionality in Windows 8 (maybe 8.1): http://www.howtogeek.com/131640/how-to-change-the-priority-of-wireless-networks-in-windows-8/ (wireless profile manager has been removed). I'll check to see if that second option is the same in English.

Comment: @BigChris This is what the wireless network properties look like in Windows 10: http://imgur.com/NfdXx0D

Comment: Tick the "look for other wireless networks while connected to this network". Tick this on the network you don't want to be connected to when there's another network that's better (preferred).

Comment: That should work like "I'm connected to this network but I'll keep looking for other networks I'm aware of. When a network on my list is higher than this one connect to it instead"... exactly what you're after... I hope! Your preferred network must be higher on your list for this to work, remember. It's all about priorities.

Comment: @BigChris If you can put that in an answer, I can accept it for people who are wondering the same thing.

Comment: Did it work, for you, though?

Comment: @BigChris I'll try it now before you answer that. However, don't be afraid to post answers that don't get accepted or even are wrong.

Answer (score 3):

On the properties page for the least preferred network: Tick **"look for other wireless networks while connected to this network"** on the network you **don't** want to be connected to, when there's a more preferred network you'd rather connect to instead (and that you're computer has connected to previously).

It's important to also make sure that the networks are sorted into your preferred order as Windows will connect you to your more preferred network only if you have set the order in Network and Sharing Centre "Manage Wireless networks" list. The list had drag-and-drop so you can arrange the networks easily.

In layman's terms: "I'm connected to this network but I'll keep looking for other networks I'm aware of. When a network on my list is higher than this one connect to it instead".

Comment: This appears to work. I'm going to another wi-free place this evening. If it works after I come back, I'll upvote, accept and award the bounty.

Comment: Sorry, apparently it actually doesn't work. I came back from the free wifi spot and it maintained access to the free wifi spot when I got back home.

Comment: Did you configure the "free wifi" network to have the "look for other wireless networks while connected to this network" ticked? And did you lower the priority of the "free" wifi network to below that of your better wireless at home?

Comment: I did both. I configured the better network to be priority 1, which should be the highest priority. i also enabled the option you mentioned. I  logged in at my aunt's place, connected to the Wi-free network, then got home a few hours later, and it stayed connected to the Wi-Free network. it also appeared like the networks changed priority around, since the better network was suddenly beneath both other networks.

Comment: The odd priority changing may be significant to your problem...